# How to get all group names and id which i joined in facebook using API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using javascript SDK v2.4 for getting all groups details which i have joined but it does not return anything.

I found the documentation from here :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/groups/

Here is my code :

```
FB.api("/userid/groups",function(response){
            if(response && !response.error){
                console.log(response);
              }
            }
        );
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `user_groups` permission is deprecated according to the [changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4). You can only get access to groups you manage, by using the `user_managed_groups` permission.